# How do I embed a UI created by GUI Builder into an email?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to embed a UI, created by GUI builder, into an email, to get information.

I couldn't use google forms, because I want to send a partially filled form to a person for review & completion.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Forms to [Pre-populate form answers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

More in line with your question, you would not be able to use the GUI builder in an email. You could however create an [HTML template file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#TemplatedHTML), and write the form in the HTML. You'll be able to use the templating to easily fill in answers. You can then take this template and call `.evaluate().getContent()` which evaluates the variables in the template, then returns the final HTML, which you can put in the email using `{htmlBody: contentOfTemplate};`.

pseudo-esque code:

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Your_file_name");
template.variable1 = "My_string";
...
var content = template.evaluate().getContent();
MailApp("Your@email.com", "Theres HTML in this email", "", {htmlBody:content});
```

Comment: Prepopulate form is a good and easy option, but how do I embed the "pre-populated form" in the email? ; I have the URL, but I can not embed it.